# What is the type of SCNVector3 components? CGFloat or Float?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

The apple documentation gives the declaration of SCNVector3 :

> typedef struct SCNVector3 { CGFloat x, y , z; } SCNVector3;

Or when trying to write an overload function :

```
func * (left: SCNVector3, right: CGFloat) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(left.x * right, left.y * right, left.z * right)
}
```

I get the *"cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type" error. Aren't left.x, left.y and left.z supposed to be CGfloat ?

How and when is it decided if CGFloat will be a double or a float?

Comment: That documentation is for Objective-C

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: But https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNVector3 is wrong for Objective-C as well (should be `float` instead of `CGFloat`). If "Swift" is selected as language then no type is shown at all.

Comment: Yes, I've filed a radar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the iOS 8.1 SDK headers, the `SCNVectorX` types are based on `Float`, as can be seen
by command-clicking on `SCNVector3`:

```
struct SCNVector3 {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var z: Float
}

func SCNVector3Make(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) -> SCNVector3
```

This is different from the OS X 10.10 SDK where `CGFloat` is used. So the documentation
seems to be wrong. The following compiles in an iOS project:

```
func * (left: SCNVector3, right: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(left.x * right, left.y * right, left.z * right)
}
```